# How to fix the FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, angular

I got an error which is `FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your angular 8 version not match with your node version in your local system, so upgrade your node version.